# writing files from Android device to other computer over USB cable

Tags: android, mysql, windows, file-io, usb

I have a small android tablet that takes a picture and needs to send that jpg image and some String texts to a windows 7 desktop PC.  The tablet will be fixed on a stand and constantly plugged into the PC by a USB cable.  tablet will be powered by the USB cable and also that is the way the files need to be sent to the folder on the PC.

the jpg pic will be put into a folder on the desktop PC hard drive and the text info will be used to update a MySQL database.

i have done a similar project before where the jpg image and text String info was sent directly from the android device to the windows PC over the internet by HTTP,  to the Apache HTTP server and a PHP script files on that server were used to receive the files and update the database.

there is a major difference in this case.  all communication between between the two devices has to use the USB cable.  where the Android tablet and windows computer is located does not have any wifi and no access to the internet.

basically need to create an Android app that can write files onto a folder on another computer that is connected to it by USB cable.

has anyone done a similar project before and what is the best way to do this?